How can I create a card or other visual please in Power Bi showing a percentage where the number of days is less than 3
I have a calculated column with a list of number of days calculated showing the time of referral to admission for several hospitals.  I need to show separate guages for each hospital or another visual to show the percentage of admissions that occurred within 3 days from referral for each hospital. I have tried several measures using calculate and count but cannot get this right.  Can anyone help please with the following:
Total referrals for each hospital
% of admissions <= 3 days
I have tried the following:
Percentage =
DIVIDE (
    COUNT ( 'column'[DateOfReferral] ),
    SUM ( 'reporting CCAdmission'[Waiting Time] ) <= 3,
    "0.00%"
)


Can you provide sample data?

Thank you for reaching out I managed to get sorted.

without your code i can't do that much but this is a guess i can do:
TotalReferrals = COUNT('column'[DateOfReferral])

AdmissionsWithin3Days = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS('reporting CCAdmission'),
    'reporting CCAdmission'[Waiting Time] <= 3
)

PercentageWithin3Days = 
DIVIDE ( [AdmissionsWithin3Days], [TotalReferrals], 0 )


Hi thank you so much. It all looks so clear on your code which I have created but looking at what would be the correct answer which would be 24% (5 admitted within 3 days from the total of 21 referrals) the code above is showing as 0.46 so I have missed something in my question to you. For the total number I have a filter field counting 'Referral ID' where the column 'Referral Status' is 'Patient Admitted' and the waiting time <=3 (waiting time measure is CCAdmission [DateTimeofAdmission] -RELATED)'COLUMN'[DateTimeOfReferral]) (within last 7 days). How do I correct please to show correct %?

Hi I have tweaked the code and it has worked.  Thank you very much for your help.
